# Java interface MouseMotionListener abstract methods: What's behind the scene?

Tags: java

I just want to know how do the abstract methods in Interfaces do these things. For example, in the MouseMotionListener interface I would have to implement the 2 abstract methods namely,

`void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
 void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)`

code snippet **`A`**:

```
    public class MouseMotionHandler implements MouseMotionListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        if(find(event.getPoint()) == null)
            setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        else
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR)); 
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        if(current != null) {

        double x = event.getX();
        double y = event.getY();

        current.setFrame(x - SIDELENGTH / 2, y - SIDELENGTH / 2, SIDELENGTH, SIDELENGTH);
        repaint();
        }
    }   
}
```

but when I swap their statements like this...

code snippet **`B`**:

```
    public class MouseMotionHandler implements MouseMotionListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        if(current != null) {

        double x = event.getX();
        double y = event.getY();

        current.setFrame(x - SIDELENGTH / 2, y - SIDELENGTH / 2, SIDELENGTH, SIDELENGTH);
        repaint();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        if(find(event.getPoint()) == null)
            setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        else
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR_CURSOR)); 
    }   
}
```

it behaves differently.
Why do the codes **`A`** and **`B`** yields different result when the two methods are just abstract - means there were no implementation of them in the MouseMotionListener to do something like determining that the mouse is moved or dragged, but only implemented them in the class that I created wherein the code that I used in my implementation doesn't really have any idea if the mouse is dragged or moved? Are there other codes that works behind these two abstract method which is not shown in API or elsewhere?

Comment: What? Your code is not determining  if the mouse was "moved" or "dragged" (the Java VM) does that for you. You are just writing code to respond to the event. So of course swapping code between the two methods will cause a different result. *the code that I used in my implementation doesn't really have any idea if the mouse is dragged or moved?* - it should. The only reason you add code to the mouseMoved() method is because your application wants to do something special. If you don't want to do anything special then don't write any code.

Comment: Your system knows whether you have dragged the mouse or moved it and therefore the corresponding methods will be called e.g. if you write `System.out.println("Hello");` in one and `System.out.println("Hi");` in the other, you will see these messages based on the events that will be produced by mouse.

Comment: @camickr thank you so much! I've been mind boggled with this for many hours and hadn't found clear answers elsewhere.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I tried it, it was fun! Thanks for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I'm not really educated about what happens exactly behind the scenes, but generally the operating system (whatever you're using) will notify anyone who wants to be notified about mouse events, in this case probably some part of all the AWT classes that are the foundation of all the graphical stuff and input etc. So now they can notify anyone when your OS receives a mouse event. But for that to happen you have to first tell the corresponding Java Code that you (or rather the objects you have instantiated) want to be notified about mouse events. So what you had to do was subscribe to this event. You did that by calling the method addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener m) of a Component (which all have this method). Now this component saved your MouseMotionListener. This could've been done with a list like in my example code below.

So to add a MML you had to create a new class, that implements the MouseMotionListener interface. Now you had to also create two methods mouseMoved and mouseDragged inside this class (where you put your logic inside).

So what's the point of this? The easiest way to imagine it is that every Component has a List of MMLs (and other Listeners). You added yours to the list before. Now when a mouse event happens, some Java class receives it from the operating system. Whatever logic there is, you don't need to understand it in detail. The only thing you need to know is that in the end your Component will also receive it together with a MouseEvent which has all the information about what happened (x- and y-positions etc.). Now it can call a method that could be named something like "notifyEveryoneWhoWantedToBeNotifiedOfMouseEvents" and will just iterate through the list of MMLs and call the two methods you implemented before, which is why your code had to be inside those two methods. Of course that's not exactly how it's implemented but the idea is the same.

```
    //Example of how the inside of such a class could look like

    //List of all the objects that want to be notified
    List<MouseMotionListener> subscriptionList = new LinkedList();

    public void addMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener mouseMotionListener)
    {
        subscriptionList.add(mouseMotionListener);
    }

    //iterate through all the subscribers and call their methods
    public void notifyEveryoneWhoWantedToBeNotifiedOfMouseEvents(MouseEvent e) {

        for(MouseMotionListener subscriber : subscriptionList)
        {
            subscriber.mouseDragged(e);
            subscriber.mouseMoved(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is really helpful and clear. :)